# How could I insert a function that allows the user to determine the URL depending on what they entered into a search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently building something for work and I have 2 text field boxes where the user can input some text and then a "View Report" Button

What I wish to have is when the button is clicked the user is redirected to a url that looks a bit like this
 http://example.com/reports/example/reports/TEXTFIELD1/reports/example/TEXTFIELD2/reports.aspx

So that the URL stays the same with the exception of the two bits that the user enters to determine the url

I have had something similar before where I had an onclick java function that took users to http://example.com/TEXTFIELD1 but I'm not sure whether this is transferable to my current issue as I have multiple parts of the url I wish to edit and are buried in a long url

All help appreciated and I hope I have explained this clearly enough  if not please let me know and i will try and provide more context

Comment: If you are building your URL on the fly - why would it matter how many parts you need to change?

Comment: What tech stack are you working with?

Comment: Every week there are a number of reports generated - rather than have to dig though 12 different pages to finally get the report I would like to build a landing page where the user would input the "week" and "store number" and press view and it would take them to www.website.com/reports/weeknumber/example/storename/example

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to create your link or simply use "+".

```
document.location.href = `http://example.com/reports/example/reports/${TEXTFIELD1}/reports/example/${TEXTFIELD2}/reports.aspx`
```

or

```
document.location.href = "http://example.com/reports/example/reports/" + TEXTFIELD1 + "/reports/example/" + TEXTFIELD2 + "/reports.aspx"
```

where TEXTFIELD1 and TEXTFIELD2 are values from your text fields.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this for me! - I have researched this a little and got some external help however I have managed to come up with this: https://codepen.io/nathan-bell/pen/rNBRZbV however it still does not function properly, would you be kind enough to help me understand why?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your pen I saw some problems, which caused your code to fail.

I'll give my best to explain why.

```
var fieldOne = document.getElementById(‘field-one’).innerHTML
var fieldTwo = document.getElementById(‘field-Two’).innerHTML

let button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   window.location.href = ‘www.website.com/reports/‘ + fieldOne +       ‘/reports/‘ + fieldTwo + ‘/reports.aspx’
});
```

So first of all you can not use those ‘ quotation marks in JS. Use one of these ' " `.

The 2nd problem you're facing is that you're getting the field values wrong in 2 ways. To get the value of an input field, you have to use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`.

The other problem is that you're getting the value of the input field when the document is ready -> so they are always empty.

Additionally you wrote `field-Two`, which should be `field-two` (JS is case-sensitive)

Apart from these mistakes, your code should work. So let me rewrite it:

```
let button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var fieldOne = document.getElementById('field-one').value
  var fieldTwo = document.getElementById('field-two').value

  var url = `www.website.com/reports/${fieldOne}/reports/${fieldTwo}/reports.aspx`;
  // or
  var url = 'www.website.com/reports/'+ fieldOne +'/reports/'+ fieldTwo +'/reports.aspx';
  window.location.href = url;
});
```

As you can see, I save the URL in a variable. That's not necessary, but I prefer to do it for the simplicity of the code. There are also 2 different ways of declaring it. Both work, it's your choice what you prefer *(note the different quotation marks wheter you use template literals or not)*